# How to calculate the Lipschitz constant for the normalization function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$?

Tags: calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I want to calculate the Lipschitz constant for the normalization function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Just as indicated @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, it is it self not Lipschitz. But I really appreciate that when we assume $\|x\|$ is bounded below, we can get the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: This function does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: hint: what about $||f(x)-f(-x)||$ when $||x||\to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}, \quad x\in X\setminus\{0\},
$$
where $X$ is a normed space IS NOT Lipschitz continue. Not even uniformly continuous. Let $e\in X$, with $\|e\|=1$. Then
$$
\|f(e/n)-f(-e/n)\|=
\left\|\frac{e/m}{\|e/m\|}-\frac{-e/n}{\|-e/n\|}\right\|
=
\left\|\frac{e}{\|e\|}+\frac{e}{\|e\|}\right\|=2,
$$
while $\|e/n-(-e/n)\|\to 0$.

However, $f$ is indeed Lipschitz continuous in $X\setminus B_r(0)$, where  $B_r(0)$ is the open ball, centered at 0, with radius $r>0$.
$$
\|f(u)-f(v)\|=
\left\|\frac{u}{\|u\|}-\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\|
=\frac{1}{\|u\|\|v\|}\big\|\|v\|u-\|u\|v\big\| \\ = 
\frac{1}{\|u\|\|v\|}\big\|\|v\|(u-v)-(\|u\|-\|v\|)v\big\|
 \\\le 
\frac{1}{\|u\|\|v\|}\big\|\|v\|(u-v)\big\|+
\frac{1}{\|u\|\|v\|}\big\|\|(\|u\|-\|v\|)v\big\| \\  \le
\frac{1}{\|u\|}\big\|u-v\big\|+
+
\frac{1}{\|u\|}\big|\|u\|-\|v\|\big|
\le \frac{2}{r}\big\|u-v\big\|.
$$

Comment: The function is continuous on $X\setminus \{0\} $ as the ratio of continuous functions. However it is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As already remarked in comments, the map is not Lipschitz on the whole space (without 0). I assume therefore that you actually mean the radial retraction, that is, the map
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}&\text{if $\lVert x\lVert \ge1$,}\\x&\text{if $\lVert x\rVert\le1$.}\end{cases}$$
The Lipschitz constant of this map depends actually on the norm. Of course, the Lipschitz constant is at most $2$, but in many cases the constant is smaller.

In fact, if the norm comes from an inner product, it can be shown that this map has Lipschitz constant $1$. On the other hand, this property characterizes inner product spaces in a sense, see e.g. [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi1787.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eesiprpr/esi1787.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. It's great to know this. I think it was quite useful to make the Lipschitz constant controlled!